# Updating variable in view constraint (SnapKit)

Tags: swift, autolayout, snapkit

View is initialized with following constraints

```
  View.snp.makeConstraints { (para) in
       View.topConstraint = para.top.equalTo(parentview.snp.top).constraint
       View.LeadingConstraint = para.leading.equalTo(parentview.snp.leading).constraint
       View.TrailingConstraint = para.trailing.equalTo(parentview.snp.trailing).constraint
       View.BottomConstraint =para.bottom.equalTo(parentview.snp.bottom).offset(-getheight).constraint
        
  }
```

where getheight = parentview.frame.size.height/2 ;

when parentview changes its dimensions.View doesnt update its height as constraints are not called again.
any way to update or recall its constraints other the remakingConstraint which is not feasible at large scale.
Have tried:

```
View.updateConstraints()
View.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
View.setNeedsLayout()
```

I need reference to each constraints because

```
if View.bottomTouch {
      View.bottomConstraint.update(offset: View. BottomConstraint.layoutConstraints[0].constant + CurrentPoint - PreviousPoint)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to use 50% of the parent view height?

```
    View.snp.makeConstraints { (para) in
        para.top.equalTo(parentview.snp.top)
        para.leading.equalTo(parentview.snp.leading)
        para.trailing.equalTo(parentview.snp.trailing)

        // 50% of the parent view height
        para.height.equalTo(parentview.snp.height).multipliedBy(0.5)

        // instead of this
        //para.bottom.equalTo(parentview.snp.bottom).offset(-getheight)
    }
```

---

**Edit** - *after comments...*

Keeping a reference to a constraint for the purposes of dragging a view is a very different question from "Keep the child view at 50% of the height of the parent view."

Give this a try...

It will create a `cyan` "parentView" with a `blue` "childView" (subview). **Dragging** the blue view  (Pan Gesture) will drag its bottom up / down. Tapping anywhere (Tap Gesture) will toggle the insets on the frame of the parentView between 20 and 60.

When the parentView frame changes - either from the tap or, for example, on device rotation - the "childView" bottom will be reset to 50% of the height of the "parentView":

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let parentView = UIView()
    let childView = UIView()
    
    // childView bottom constraint
    var bc: Constraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        parentView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        childView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        parentView.addSubview(childView)
        view.addSubview(parentView)
        
        parentView.snp.makeConstraints { para in
            para.top.leading.trailing.bottom.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).inset(20.0)
        }
        
        // childView's bottom constraint offset will be set in viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        childView.snp.makeConstraints { para in
            para.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            bc = para.bottom.equalToSuperview().constraint
        }
        
        let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panHandler(_:)))
        childView.addGestureRecognizer(p)
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }

    @objc func tapHandler(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        
        // on tap, toggle parentView inset
        //  between 20 and 60
        // this will trigger viewDidLayoutSubviews(), where the childView bottom
        //  constraint will be reset to 50% of the parentView height
        var i: CGFloat = 60.0
        if parentView.frame.origin.x > 20 {
            i = 20.0
        }
        parentView.snp.updateConstraints { para in
            para.top.leading.trailing.bottom.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).inset(i)
        }
        
    }

    @objc func panHandler(_ g: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        
        let translation = g.translation(in: g.view)

        // update bottom constraint constant
        bc.layoutConstraints[0].constant += translation.y
        
        // reset gesture translation
        g.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    }
    
    var parentViewHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // reset childView's bottom constraint
        //  to 50% of its superView's height
        //  ONLY if parentView frame height has changed
        if parentView.frame.height != parentViewHeight {
            parentViewHeight = parentView.frame.height
            bc.layoutConstraints[0].constant = -parentViewHeight * 0.5
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Mad respect! wrote over 3k lines of constraints without thinking of this.I was using top bottom leading trailing because i was saving those constrainst for later changes too but ill find a way.

Comment: self.View.bottomConstraint = para.bottom.equalTo(parentview.snp.bottom).offset(-getheight).constraint is an extra now.is there any way i can get reference to it.As i need it.

Comment: @Divine - I think you need to explain **why** you need that.

Comment: To calculate probable first touch offset from anyside.

Comment: @Divine - hmm? I would expect you to be checking the frame when touched... I can't think of a case where you'd do anything with the constraint.

Comment: sides need to be distinguished.Multilplier is solving ratio problem but i cant get reference to bottom any more.

Comment: @Divine - are you trying to drag the view? Or, drag the bottom up and down?

Comment: bottom up and down

Comment: @Divine - that's a very different question from your original post. See the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: nice and correct approach but not feasible at large scale.OP was just about any function which can recall constraints for me.I solved it by making my constraints variable free.
self.View.bottomConstraint = para.bottom.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.5).constraint

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check whether the `getheight` value did update when the parent view layout change. In order to reload the existing constraints, you may need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` of your parent view.

Comment: everything is good.
If i manually call my constraints then it gets corrected.Am asking for any method with which  i can update or refresh my constraints.